# Create index on column rowid of rowid table

Tags: sqlite

There is the sqlite table structure:

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp1lp.png

I create two index, the first one is:

`CREATE INDEX atc_index ON category (
    ATC
);`

The second one is:

`CREATE INDEX atc_index ON category (
    id,
    ATC
);`

Because id is primary integer key, so the id is rowid. Therefore I think the two index is same. But I found the two index will cost different time on the same query. In average, the time that the first index cost is ten times than the second. Is the SQL query matters or there are another reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both indexes are sorted lists with each entry containing the ATC value and the rowid.

However, the first index is sorted by ATC, while the second one is sorted by the rowid. This means that the latter is useful only to search for a rowid value, which does not need an index to begin with.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand the last sentence -- which does not need an index to begin with. Could you please explain more

Comment: The table itself is sorted by the rowid. The DB uses the rowid value from the index to find the corresponding table row.